# Flutter Execution failed for task ':stack_appodeal_flutter:compileDebugKotlin'. >

Tags: flutter, appodeal

I tried to integrate Appodeal  into my Flutter Project using latest [stack_appodeal_flutter 1.2.0](https://pub.dev/packages/stack_appodeal_flutter) Package.
I followed their instruction still got this error. Appreciate any help.

this is my Android build gradle

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://artifactory.appodeal.com/appodeal" }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have added

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.appodeal.ads:sdk:2.11.0.+'
    ...
}
```

this in your build.gradle (module: app), please remove that and run again. Their documentation in pub.dev is little misunderstanding.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).